# Creating an automatic and self-generating weekday data entry sheet in google sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet, schedule, weekday

In short, I need admins at my work to be able to punch in whether someone is on leave or not into a sheet that informs other sheets to create daily staffing lineups all based in Google Sheets. Right now, I have them deleting whole columns of values and keeping track of what day it is every day. Obviously this is open to error and is a task I'd like to eliminate.

Essentially, I have 7 cell-wide table with the first one being =today() and each one in that row being =today()+1 through =today()+6. What I want to see happen is for the values (underneath) that correspond to that day move (to the left) as the date updates. Furthermore, icing on the cake, I need the new =today()+6 to automatically generate with "no" in each cell under that newly generated date (column H in the below example).

For example, in my submitted sheet, today Karen is OFF in column B. However, in two days time she'll be on VAC which, by that time, should be column B.

I appreciate any help.

[Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teM7w.png)

Here's a link to the sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sI1TazFNTSmh1VmQW4WOW0aT2W580vg2PsZ--umLlXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be done if you change the way your managers enter data. If they fill out the data in a table like this

[image]

then your master table would look like this

[image]

you need to clear the contents in the range `B5:H9` and copy the following formula into cell `B5`

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRUE&TRUE&$A5:$A,{(Sheet2! $A:$A<=B3)&(Sheet2!$B:$B>=B3)&Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet2!$D:$D},2,FALSE), "no"))`

Then you need to extend this formula to cell `B9`